# Настройка адресации субдомена на ip

Tags: сервер, ip, хостинг, dns, домен

В наличии оплаченное доменное имя на reg.ru (пусть mysite.ru) с настроенным DNS на хостинг-сервис hostinger.ru, на котором сейчас находится веб-сайт, а также домашний веб-сервер, работа с которым в данный момент осуществляется по ip:port/page в строке браузера.

Интересует возможность переноса адреса сервера на субдомен, а т.е. замещение ip:port на sub.mysite.ru при наличии рабочего веб-сайта на mysite.ru

В панели управления Hostinger удалось создать субдомен, однако не удалось понять, какие настройки DNS должны быть изменены для адресации именно субдомена на сервер. На reg.ru есть возможность редактирования DNS-серверов (в данный момент прописано 4 записи от ns1.hostinger.ru до ns4.hostinger.ru), на Hostinger есть "Редактор DNS-зон", который доступен только для платной подписки, а также детали имён серверов, в которых указаны ip-адреса для каждой вышеназванной записи, а также адрес для направления А-записи домена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, вам надо создать А запись, с указанием IP адреса субдомена. Я бы еще добавил CNAME запись.